# $element.show() not working in IE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, visibility

I have a little `div` stored in `$tip` which I want to display at the user's click position, when they hit a certain link.
This is what I'm doing, it's part of a plugin where `$this` is a dynamically created known object:

```
$this.children('.menu').children('.details').bind('click', function(e){
   $tip = $('#resizetip');
   tiptext = "some text for my sweet little tip";
   $tip.css('top',e.clientY);
   $tip.css('left',e.clientX);
   $tip.html(tiptext);
   $tip.show();
});
```

The tip shows up where expected, just fine in Chrome and FF but I don't know why it's not working in IE8 and even in IE9. I tried `console.log($tip.html());` and it gave the expected output, so I know it's there somewhere. I tried to output the coordinates, and it was fine.

Then I tried `$('#resizetip').show();` explicitly from the console, and it worked! It showed up, exactly where it should be. But why doesn't it work in the code? I tried adding another line of `$tip.show();` just in case for some inexplicable reason the first one couldn't be fired, but that didn't help.

### Edit

I've added an edit to the code to show where `e` is coming from, but I know that's not the problem because when I output `e.clientX` to console, the output is fine.

Comment: Where are you pulling in `e` from? Can you put together a jsFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Can you post the code with more context and possibly a example at http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a problem of "e" not being available. Check out this site for an explanation of this problem across browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Basically you have to check if "e" exists and if not assign it with window.event:

function doSomething(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
        ....
}

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need something similar to:

```
if (!e){ 
  var e = window.event
}
```

near the top of your function. `e` may not be defined for IE, so you'll need to revert to [`window.event`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535863%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can read more [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html)

[clientX documentation for IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

Set some units and use pageX and pageY instead

```
$tip.css({
    'top', e.pageY+ "px", 
    'left',e.pageX + "px"
);
```

Comment: Not required - jQuery adds `px` if you just supply integers :)